# Can AtomicInteger replace synchronized?

Tags: java

The javadoc for the java.util.concurrent.atomic package says the following:

> A small toolkit of classes that
>   support lock-free thread-safe
>   programming on single variables.

But I don't see any thread-safe (synchronized or Lock) code inside any of the AtomicInteger or AtomicBoolean classes.

So, are these 2 the same:

1.

```
int i;
synchronized(this){i++;}
```

2.

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
i.getAndIncrement();
```

**Update**: Thanks for the answers. Is volatile needed when I use AtomicInteger?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They would offer the same atomicity.  The only thing you must be aware of is any time you read i you must wrap it with synchronized also

```
synchronized(this){ return i;}
```

Edit to answer your edit:

Volatile is not necessary for your AtomicInteger.  To prove that declare the AtomicInteger final.  The only reason you would need the AtomicInteger to be volatile is if the AtomicInteger field itself changes.  Similar to:

```
volatile AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void work(){
    i.incrementAndGet();
    //...do some other stuff
    i = new AtomicInteger(10);//because the field i is changing the field needs to be volatile 
}
```

As you can imagine that shouldn't be the case, so you shouldn't have to worry about the field being volatile.

Answer (score 9):

They are equivalent functionally, but there is a subtle difference. `synchronized` has the overhead of acquiring and releasing the monitor on `this`, while `AtomicInteger` is implemented with a native method call, so it will be significantly faster.

Comment: Do you have a source that native method calls of AtomicInteger are significantly faster than using `synchronized`?

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `java.util.concurrent.atomic`.  The stated purpose is to allow use of hardware atomic primitives.  The implementation isn't required to do so but most modern hardware supports atomic CAS, which will be much faster.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they're functionally equivalent.

If you're in an ultra-high contention environment, you may see performance differences, but that's highly unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

AtomicInteger uses sun.misc.Unsafe underneath to perform the atomic updates.

So, in answer to your question, yes, AtomicInteger **is thread-safe**.

Answer (score 1):

> Is volatile needed when I use AtomicInteger?

Not necessarily.  Considering your example:

- if `i` is a local variable, or
- if `i` is a `final` attribute, or
- if the current thread and the thread that initialized (or last updated) the `i` variable have synchronized after that event,

then it makes no difference if you declare `i` as volatile or not.