# Is there a better AtomicInteger compare feature for race conditions?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition

I am trying to write a decorator to an existing class that rejects if there are not enough resources available. Here is an example version of the code with no multithreading at all:

```java
public interface Handler {
    boolean handleTask(Task myTask); // returns true if successful, false if failure
}

public interface Task {
    int getResources();
    // Among other things
}

public BlockingHandler implements Handler {
    private int occupied;
    private final int limit;

    private final Handler backingHandler;

    BlockingHandler(Handler backingHandler) {
        this.backingHandler = backingHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleTask(Task myTask) {
        if(myTask.getResources() + occupied > limit) return false;
        occupied += myTask.getResources();
        return backingHandler.handleTask(myTask);
    }

    // Don't worry about this part, I'm not doing it this way, I just want the code to make sense
    public void notifyResourceRelease(Task finishedTask) {
        if(finishedTask.isDone()) occupied -= myTask.getResources();
    }
}
```

The problem is, this `handleTask` method can be called on multiple threads, and I want to be very fast (i.e. avoid `synchronized`). It's not enough to make `occupied` be `volatile` or an `AtomicInteger`, because a race condition is still possible, for instance:

```
Thread 1: call handleTask
Thread 1: call atomicOccupied.get()
Thread 2: call handleTask
Thread 1: evaluate if condition
Thread 2: call atomicOccupied.get()
```

Is it possible to do this without using `synchronized`? Is there, for instance, an extended `AtomicInteger` class with a more powerful `compareAndSet`?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Why don't you use an ArrayBlockingQueue? That class is built for this type of functionality

Comment: I believe this has already been answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210292/can-atomicinteger-replace-synchronized

Comment: @durron597 You can use `if (!semaphore.tryAcquire()) throw new SomeException();`. It is essentially an AtomicInteger under the hood, so I'd use that instead of reimplementing a very similar logic manually.

Comment: @assylias Never mind I misremembered how `Semaphore` works, I remembered `.acquire()` but not `.tryAcquire()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this without using synchronized? Is there, for instance, an extended AtomicInteger class with a more powerful compareAndSet?

You should be able to do that without a `synchronized` block.  No there isn't more extended `AtomicInteger` class.

If I'm understanding you requirements, you can do this in a `while` loop.  Something like:

```
final AtomicInteger occupied = new AtomicInteger();
...
int prev;
int numResources = myTask.getResources();
do {
    prev = occupied.get();
    if (numResources + prev > limit) return false;
} while (!occupied.compareAndSet(prev, prev + numResources));
```

This loop will spin updating the occupied if possible.  If it reaches the limit it will return false.  You need the spin because if other threads have updated the occupied count between when you get the previous value and you go to adjust the value then you will need to loop around and get the occupied count again.  This is a typical pattern.

---

Also, you need to use `AtomicInteger` over `volatile` because you are using `compareAndSet`. See this question for more information:

[What is the difference between using a volatile primitive over atomic variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859008/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-volatile-primitive-over-atomic-variables)

Comment: I thought of this but I wasn't sure it was faster than `synchronized`

Comment: In most situations, it will be faster than blocking @durron597.   The only exception is if there are a ton of threads and the occupied update is highly contended.  Even then it might outperform a `synchronized` but a blocking queue or something might outperform both.

Comment: @durron597 Consider that a `synchronized` does at least one volatile read (`AtomicInteger.get` and one volatile set `AtomicInteger.set`).  This would certainly be higher performing.

Comment: I think the answer is "yes it is required" but I just want to check: is `AtomicInteger` still required or will `volatile` suffice?

Comment: Use AtomicInteger and declare it final.  It wraps a volatile field (with some CAS/atomic instructions), but you need not worry about it.  The volatile increment of a primitive is not atomic, there are plenty of explanations on why.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` is required because of the `compareAndSet(...)` @durron597.