# Java spring multithreading atomic issue

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a class

```
@Component
public class JmxConf implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5586922486161726170L;

  private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public AtomicInteger getCount() {
    return count;
  }
}
```

And I autowired this class to another

```
@Component
public class QueueListener {
  private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

  @Autowired
  private JmxConf jmxConf;


  public doIt(){
    if(jmxConf.getCount().get()>.....) {

      jmxConf.getCount().incrementAndget();

      ...... 
      executor.submit(new thread here);

      jmxConf.getCount().decrementAndget();
    }
  }
}
```

We have one singleton bean which has a state but access to this state is controlled by an atomic variable. Will this class be thread-safe? And if not, why. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that AtomicInteger for ?

Comment: you need to give more details on what are you trying to achieve... To implement a thread safe singleton you need a private instance that is create once and a public synchronized getter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it won't be atomic.  You have a race here:

```
if(jmxConf.getCount().get()>.....) {

  jmxConf.getCount().incrementAndget();
```

Imagine the scenario where the `greater than` is some number, just say 10.

```
if(jmxConf.getCount().get() > 10) { 

  jmxConf.getCount().incrementAndget();
```

What if, when the thread hits the `if` the value is *9*.  When it gets to the increment it was already incremented by another thread to *10* and now you increment it to a value of *11*.

You should use compareAndSet.

```
while(true){
  int value = jmxConf.getCount().get() + 1;
  if(value > 10){
     break;
  }
  if(mxConfg.getCount().compareAndSet(value-1, value){
     executor.submit(new thread here);
     jmxConf.getCount().decrementAndGet();
     break;
   }
}
```

You can read more on atomic references and `compareAndSet` offered by Java.

---

So why do we need the `while(true)`?  The compareAndSet function [takes two parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet%28int,%20int%29)

```
public final boolean compareAndSet(int expect, int update)
```

The method says "Try to update the AtomicInteger in a thread safe matter, here is the value I expect it to be currently and here is the value I want to update it with.  If, when trying to do the update, the value of the AtomicInteger is what I expect than you can safely do the update.  If it's not what I expect it to be then don't update it and notify me that you didn't update it."

Let's say we enter the `if` and the value is *5* if another thread is also trying to update the AtomicInteger with a value of *5* both threads will have an expectation of *5* as the parameter.  Because it is thread-safe only one thread can win which means one will fail (the compareAndSet will return false on failure).  In that case we should re-try the compareAndSet until we succeed or exceed the threshold in which we `break`.

Comment: Why the `while(true)`

Comment: if the value is 5 the if expression will short-circuit and the compareAndSet will never be reached... maybe you meant a value bigger than 10?

Comment: @Stephan Good catch, you're right.  It should be `less than`. Made an update.

Comment: Thank you, but is it ok that executor variable is not syncronized?

Comment: Yes it's OK as the `executor` variable itself is thread-safe.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to skip while(true) loop. May be use Locks?

Comment: @avalon You can use locks, yes.  Though you run into your own separate issues with blocking.

Comment: maybe he can use a CountDownLatch (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and when it reaches 0 to reinitialize it ...

Comment: @John Vint Thank you, but is your approach standartized or the most applicable? Why do you think I will run into issues? May be you know how to replace loop with Locks there? Thanks

Comment: @avalon The incrementAndGet uses an almost identical implementation with the exception of the `count <= 10` check.  So I think the implementation I have should suffice.

Comment: @avalon I am sure you will run into issues as get then check then set isn't atomic.

Comment: @John Vint, please tell, why break in else clause? If value<10 && thread sees what expected than do what we need and break, no? I feel that it will be an infinite loop

Comment: Well you break in the while loop for the same reason your initial `doIt` doesn't retry.  If you look at your code, if the condition is not met it simply returns out.  My implementation achieves the same functionality.

Comment: @John Vint Ok, got it, sorry, but what if compareAndSet method returns false? It means that there another thread that incremented value, but why to break in this case? i still want to run my method. Sorry If I`m stupid, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75842/discussion-between-avalon-and-john-vint).

Answer (score -4):

AtomicInteger is thread-safe so this will be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the -2 but AtomicInteger is threadsafe as per:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

in particular:
"For example, classes AtomicLong and AtomicInteger provide atomic increment methods. "

Comment: I didn't -1 but the issue here isn't thread-safeness it's atomicity.  Your answer doesn't answer the OP's question which is why you received the -1s

Comment: "For example, classes AtomicLong and AtomicInteger provide atomic increment methods."

Comment: *And* the question was "Will this class be thread-safe?" - helping out has never been this tough before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210292/can-atomicinteger-replace-synchronized

Comment: @Syntax, you are right that the AtomicInteger class is thread-safe.  But the operation as a whole is not.  If the rules for the operation is that the AtomicInteger can never be incremented greater than a value, the above code offered by the OP fails due to atomicity issues.

Comment: The OP asked if it was thread-safe. I answered correctly.
Not sure where max value comes into it but atomicity is guaranteed anyway by AtomicInteger as per my comments and link to the concurrent javadoc.

Comment: Atomicity of single instruction operations, sure, but not atomic get, check then set operations like the OP is asking for.  He asked if it was thread-safe but there was implication as to if his code itself is thread-safe.

Comment: It is thread-safe though!! He's using AtomicInteger and incrementAndGet/decrementAndGet methods - guaranteed to be lock-free and thread-safe

Comment: /sigh but the operation as a whole is not atomic and as a whole isn't thread safe.  At least 3 other people agree with me here.

Comment: No worries - I'll make friends one day and then be better at Java.